# Validation Rules Confusion

Tags: validation-rule

I have to implement a Validation rule where 'Fees_per_Student' field can be modified only by System Administrator.->->

```
IF(
ISCHANGED(Fees_per_student__c) && 
NOT(ISNEW())  && 
$Profile.Name  = 'System Administrator',
false, true)
```

. Is this correct as I am reverting true and false statements in if statement? Or Is the following Correct?

````
ISCHANGED( Fees_per_student__c ) && NOT(ISNEW()) && NOT($Profile.Name = 'System Administrator') ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine structurally to invert Boolean values as shown in your first example (although `NOT()` is often clearer), but that first example doesn't do what you're aiming at. Since Validation Rules go off when they evaluate to `TRUE`, that's going to block edits *other than* a System Administrator updating that field.

The second form looks correct to me.

I always recommend using a [Custom Permission](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=custom_perms_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=0) instead of an explicit check for a named Profile, as it gives you greater flexibility in permissioning your users

Comment: My objective is - Only System Admin should be able to edit 'Fees_per_student' field. Users with other profiles should not edit. So according to this first one is correct?

Comment: No. The second example is correct

Comment: okay, thank you